# What does Oracle use "select 1 from sys.obj$ where 1=0" for?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was in our Oracle DB and saw this in the messages.

```
select 1 from sys.obj$ where 1=0;
```

[image: Statements - Log]

I'm curious as to what it does. Is it just a session being initiated, a check to see if there is a sign of life?

Comment: What is "in the messages"?  Are you seeing this query in, say, a session trace?  Coming from an application or part of a bit of recursive SQL that Oracle is executing?

Comment: In the sqldeveloper program. It has a message window that is basically a log of commands it Oracle has executed.

Comment: How many times has that statement been executed?  You should be able to find that with this query: `select executions, sql_text from gv$sql where lower(sql_text) like '%select%1%from%sys.obj%where%1%=%0';`.

Comment: I apparently do not have high enough permissions to look at global objects. I kicked it over to our security team to look at. It's probably nothing but it has the cadence of someone seeing if they got into a database. If they turn anything up I'll update.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith is this the way sqldeveloper detects whether you have access to system tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query is automatically generated by Oracle SQL Developer, it's nothing nefarious.

I can't tell exactly what the query is used for.  But when I looked for it on a few hundred of our databases I found about 20 rows for completely unrelated users and databases.  The only thing they had in common was the `MODULE` was set to "SQL Developer".

```
select executions, parsing_schema_name, module, first_load_time
from gv$sql
where sql_text = 'select 1 from sys.obj$ where 1=0';
```

Further queries on `GV$SQL` and `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL` show other boring data dictionary queries being run at the same time.  Which leads me to believe it's one of a set of background queries run for some Oracle SQL Developer feature.

```
select executions, parsing_schema_name, first_load_time, gv$sql.*
from gv$sql
where parsing_schema_name = '<user from above>'
order by gv$sql.first_load_time desc;
```